# Implementing elevate zoom on spree commerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, spree, elevatezoom

I'm trying to implement elevate zoom on a Spree eCommerce store. So far the zoom is working for the main image, but when a product has more than one image I cannot make that the zoom takes the selected thumbnail.
I have tried the examples they have on their page, but the galleries they use are very simple and my thumbnails are a bit different since they are inside a carousel.

This is the code in my product show.html.erb

`<div id="main-image" class="mainImage">`

```
<% image = @product.images.first  %>
<%= image_tag(image.attachment.url(:product), id: "zoom_08", class: "img-responsive", 'data-zoom-image' => image.attachment.url(:large)) %>
```

`</div>`

and at the end of the file I have the javascript

`<script type="text/javascript">`

```
 $("#zoom_08").elevateZoom({
     //gallery:'product-thumbnails',
     //galleryActiveClass: 'active',
     zoomType: "inner",
     cursor: "crosshair",                                    
     zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
     zoomWindowFadeOut: 500,
     lensFadeIn: 500,
     lensFadeOut: 500
 });
```

`</script>`

On my product.js.coffee I added a line to modify the "data-zoom-image" property of the main image and it works

...

thumbnails.find('li').on 'mouseenter', (event) ->

```
  ($ '#main-image img').attr 'src', ($ event.currentTarget).find('a').attr('href')

  **($ '#main-image img').attr 'data-zoom-image', ($ event.currentTarget).find('img').attr('zoom')**
```

...

But the elevate zoom script, doesn't recognize this change.

Any ideas would be very appreciated!

Comment: After going over and over my code, I found the problem. I was creating adding the "data-image" and "data-zoom-image" properties on the image tag and they needed to be created on the <a> tag. 
<%= link_to(image_tag(i.attachment.url(:mini), class: "thumbnail"), i.attachment.url(:product), 'data-image' => i.attachment.url(:product), 'data-zoom-image' => i.attachment.url(:large)) %>

Comment: did you get it working as mine is not working

Comment: Hi Lakshya, yes, in the i got it working, please read my previous comment where i explained what i was doing wrong and how i fixed it